# Custom tab control with close buttons

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I want to have modern framework tab control (like in image) with close buttons that are removing tab like in chrome or firefox

https://i.stack.imgur.com/04sFX.png
is there any custom tab control like this or way to do this?

Comment: What are going to do when they "close" a tab?  TabPages are not like browser tabs

Comment: i meant delete tab, i will edit that

Answer (score 1):

I've used fabtab in the past and it provides the features you are looking for. It is WPF.

https://fabtab.codeplex.com/

Comment: im using winforms and i dont know i could even add it to custom control which set of is metro framework